# Removing and nil out object used in animation won't nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

Using Obj-c to animate alpha continously but when I try to nil our and remove the subview it sticks around and won't delete or stop animating?

```
-(void)flashFingerPrint{
    [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:1 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse|UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
         self.purpleFingerPrint.alpha = 0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        nil;
    }];
}



-(void)hidePurpleHelper {

    if(nil != self.purpleFingerPrint && nil != self.purpleFingerPrint) {

        // add it to the screen with animation
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.2 options:(UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut) animations:^{
            self.purpleHelperView.alpha = 0;
            self.purpleFingerPrint.alpha = 0;
            self.purpleFingerPrint = nil;
            [self.view willRemoveSubview:self.purpleFingerPrint];

        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            // nothing
            self.purpleHelperView = nil;
            self.purpleFingerPrint = nil;
            [self.view willRemoveSubview:self.purpleFingerPrint];
        }];
    }
}
```

I call the hide function but the fingerprint still shows on screen and still flashing?

Comment: no need to repeat the check here `if(nil != self.purpleFingerPrint && nil != self.purpleFingerPrint)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need

```
[self.purpleFingerPrint removeFromSuperview];
```